# Can't remove element using splice

Tags: javascript, splice

I have an array with length 9. I want to remove elem from array.

```js
arr = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 0],
  [2, 1],
  [2, 2]
]

let elem = [2, 0];
let index = arr.indexOf(elem)
if (index !== -1) {
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(elem), 1)
}

console.log(arr)
```

Why my splice does not work?

Comment: what is that `special element`

Comment: I mean I want to remove [2, 0] from array. Special element is elem

Comment: what is wrong is your assumption of `let elem = [2, 0];
let index = arr.indexOf(elem)`

Comment: your index returns `-1` that's why it is not executing `splice`

Comment: I know that it returns -1 but why? the [2, 0] exist why it is returning -1?

Comment: `[2, 0] === [2, 0]` will return false because these are *different* objects

Comment: Oooh thats right. So how i can remove this element?

Comment: You can compare the contents of the two via `a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1]`  or other piece of code that will check if each value matches the other array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with another object reference than the same object reference. This means, if you have another array to check against, you need to iterate it element by element. For this, you could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and iterate all elements with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

For splicing, you need the found index, and not to find another index, because you have it already.

```js
var arr = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]],
    elem = [2, 0],
    index = arr.findIndex(a => a.every((v, i) => elem[i] === v));

console.log(index);

if (index !== -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` instead: (more about .filter() [here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
arr = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 0],
  [2, 1],
  [2, 2]
]

let elem = [2, 0];
const newArray = arr.filter(item => !(item[0] === elem[0] && item[1] === elem[1]));

console.log(newArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This simply checks if both parts of the array match, then reverses the result, so only those that **DON'T** match are returned

Not that it makes much difference nowadays but `.filter()` is also faster - [Here's a test I ran on JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter-js/1)

Comment: Thumbs up, I was also going to do that with `Array.prototype.filter()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function

```js
arr = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 0],
  [2, 1],
  [2, 2]
]
let m = [];
let elem = [2, 0];
let __j = elem.toString();

let k = arr.filter(function(item) {
  let __i = item.toString();
  return __i !== __j
})


console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON object to remove quickly a element:

```js
arr = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 0],
  [2, 1],
  [2, 2]
]

let elem = [2, 0];
var arrjson = arr.map(JSON.stringify);
var elemjson = [elem].map(JSON.stringify);
//console.log(arrjson); //console.log(elemjson); 
var index = arrjson.indexOf(elemjson[0]);
arrjson.splice(index,1);
//console.log(arrjson);
var arrresult = arrjson.map(JSON.parse);
console.log(arrresult);
```